# Mixing ingredients ahead of time

Tags: baking

Can you mix all dry ingredients for a cake and place ingredients in container and make cake the next day?

Comment: Do you have a specific recipe you're looking at? Depending on the mixing method, it may or may not be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I store baking powder together with baking soda?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64162/can-i-store-baking-powder-together-with-baking-soda)

Comment: @Catija as Jefromi noted, the title of that other question really should be: "can I store the dry ingredients together?" — it's not just about baking powder and baking soda.

Comment: Okay, I changed the title for them. As this discussion demonstrates, that'll make it a more useful question for future readers, and it doesn't actually alter the meaning significantly.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, yes.  (it depends on the exact recipe).

There's actually a whole category of crafts / gifts for various 'mixes in a jar' where you mix up all of the dry goods, put it in a jar, decorate it, and label it w/ instructions on what else needs to be done.

**update:**

To clarify -- if the recipe calls for mixing all of the dry ingredients together before you start, there will be absolutely no problem.  If you specifically go out and search for ["Mix in a Jar"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mix+in+a+jar+recipes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) recipes, you should have no problem.

The issue comes when the dry ingredients aren't added all at the same time -- sugar is often mixed with the wet ingredients ... it might be used for creaming the butter, or in a chiffon or angel food cake whipped with the egg whites.  In those cases, you may need to hold back an ingredient from the others, not pre-mix them.

Comment: I generally agree that this is true, since the question is a bit broad, could you possibly expand your answer to explain which types of cake do better with this and which will likely not work well?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can! I do it all the time when I plan to cook with my 2 year old. It really keeps the mess down and saves time. I also mix pancake/waffle dry ingredients the night before because mornings are hard enough! :)